# Surjective map from a globally generated vector bundle to its determinant

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $X$ be a non-singular quasi-projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$ and $E$ be a globally generated locally-free sheaf on $X$ of rank $r$. Denote by $L$ the determinant of $E$. Does there exists $r-1$-global sections $s_1,...,s_{r-1} \in H^0(E)$ such that the  morphism $$E \to L \mbox{ sending } s \mbox{ to } s \wedge s_1 \wedge s_2 \wedge ... \wedge s_{r-1}$$
is surjective?

Comment: No, that is not true.  Let $X$ be $\mathbb{CP}^r$ and let $E$ be $\mathcal{O}(1)\oplus \mathcal{O}(1)$, so that $L$ is $\mathcal{O}(2)$.  Then the maximal possible rank of your map is $h^0(X,\mathcal{O}(1))$, which is strictly less than $h^0(X,\mathcal{O}(2))$.

Comment: My example is the one that arises in the "basepoint free pencil trick" of Castelnuovo.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Jason Starr I'm not sure I follow your answer. If $r=1$ and I take the section $x\oplus y$, then it seems that $(0\oplus -y) \wedge (x\oplus y)=xy$, $(0\oplus -x)\wedge (x\oplus y)=x^2$ and $(y\oplus 0) \wedge (x\oplus y)=y^2$? Is there some tragic error here?

Comment: I forgot to write that $r$ is at least $2$.